# Setting up UpSource behind IIS Reverse Proxy for HTTPS ~ TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: iis, https, typeerror, reverse-proxy, upsource

I am trying to set up UpSource, along with YouTrack, TeamCity and Hub, over https on a single server using a reverse IIS  Proxy.

The situation is as follows:

The http version of UpSource is located at http://server.company.com:8081/upsource and works fine. I want it to be accessible via https://server.company.com/upsource. However, while it is possible to access UpSource via the https address, the connection is immediately interrupted and the following error message comes up:

```
Backend is not available

TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I find this error to be weird and confusing, considering that the backend appears to be available and running since http://server.company.com:8081/upsource works perfectly.

As for my configuration, I set it up mostly following the steps as outlined in [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/proxy-configuration.html), making amends where needed to account for the fact that we have four JetBrains services running on a single server and over the same IIS Reverse Proxy.

The current web.config for the IIS Proxy reads as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to TeamCity" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^teamcity(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server.company.com{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to Hub" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^hub(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server.company.com:8082/hub{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SCHEMA" value="https" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" value="https" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to YouTrack" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^youtrack(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server.company.com:8080/youtrack{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SCHEMA" value="https" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" value="https" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to UpSource" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^upsource(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server.company.com:8081/upsource{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SCHEMA" value="https" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" value="https" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to Collaboration General" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server.company.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxUrl="6144" maxQueryString="4096" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As I mentioned, this already works fine for TeamCity and Hub. However, for UpSource, there seems to be something still missing, which is likely related to the "TypeError: Failed to fetch". I've tried looking that up, but could not find any helpful information thus far .

If anyone has any ideas how to resolve this, I'd be more than happy to get additional input on this

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out how to do this:

The above configuration of the web.config is actually correct. However, the following steps need to be performed in addition, and in the correct order:

NOTE: All commands beginning with `hub.bat` need to be performed on the `hub.bat` file in `[Hub Installation Directory]\bin` and all commands beginning with `upsource.bat` need to be performed on the `upsource.bat` file in `[UpSource Installation Directory]\bin`.

```
upsource.bat stop
hub.bat stop

hub.bat configure --listen-port 8082 --base-url https://server.company.com/hub
upsource.bat configure --listen-port 8081 --base-url=https://server.company.com/upsource --hub-url=https://server.company.com/hub/hub

hub.bat start
upsource.bat start --J-Dbundle.websocket.compression.enabled=false
```

NOTE: I don't know why, but Hub  appends an extra /hub after its base address, that's why the hub-url setting for UpSource ends with `/hub/hub`.

After that, all I needed to do was add the redirection URL to the list of allowed redirection URLs for UpSource in Hub > Settings > Services > UpSource, and now it works perfectly.

Well, almost perfectly. Whenever the server gets restarted I need to manually restart UpSource since I've not yet figured out a way to register upsource as a service with the `--J-Dbundle.websocket.compression.enabled=false` parameter, but apart from that, everything works perfectly.

Comment: You may add the command line parameter for disabling compression to the arguments tag in conf\internal\launcher.service.settings.xml if running as a service.